# SugarCRM Extensions, modules and views

Tags: module, view, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I recently got employed at a company that mostly develops modules for SuiteCRM which is based upon SugarCRM. However there are a few points I don't really get at the moment and Google hasn't been too helpful either. I've been told that most of the development is done in the 'custom' folder. However during my training I've used both the 'modules' folder and the 'Extensions folder'.

My question would be:

- When and why do you use the Extensions folder? (When you're extending
  existing modules?)
- When and why do you use the modules folder? (When you're making a
  brand new module?)
- Also, one time I had to make a new class extending the default
  ViewList class, the other time I had to make a new smarty template.
  What's up with that? When do you have to extend the default class and
  when do you have to make a new view?

Comment: one thing and most important point i learned why most of the development must be done in custom folder is to make your codes upgrade safe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to add custom field manually or to allow custom extensions within the framework or to change the behavior or data type of fields, then you need to do modification in custom Ext directory.

   You will found more details related to extension [Sugar Doc](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.7/04_Extension_Framework/Extensions/Extensions/) And [Example](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.7/03_Module_Framework/03_Vardefs/Examples/Manually_Creating_Custom_Fields/)
2. For upgrade safe development you will find more examples on [Upgrade Safe](http://developer.sugarcrm.com/tag/upgrade-safe/)
3. When you need to change the behavior of existing functionality of list view then by extending the default class you can achieve it. [Example](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/03_Module_Framework/01_MVC/Examples/Changing_the_ListView_Default_Sort_Order/)